# Javascript: Replace whole anchor with text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery.

Is there any way I can replace a anchor text with its own text in the following **p** tag?

```
<p>
    <a href="#">Some Text1</a> some text goes here 
    <a href="#">Some Text2</a> some other text goes here 
</p>
```

Desired Output:

```
<p>
    Some Text1 some text goes here 
    Some Text2 some other text goes here 
</p>
```

Comment: As I can see, its not replacing anchor with text, but just removing `<a href="#">` and `</a>`... So?

Comment: Why do you need this?  How are you hoping to achieve it?  What research have you done?

Comment: I am just trying to remove all the anchors in specified element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `.replaceWith()` like

```
$('p a').each(function(){
      $(this).replaceWith($(this).text());          
});
```

Comment: Any reason to down it..??

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
$('a').replaceWith(function() {
    return $(this).text();
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/TBV5J/)

Obviously, you need to make the `a` selector something more specific to your needs, as I hope you're not trying to reomve all links from a page.

Comment: Return statement forgotten.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to strip tags is this one:

```
var paragraph = $('p');
paragraph.html(paragraph.text());
```

If you have other tags that you want to keep, refer to Rory's answer that only replaces the `a` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("p").text("Some Text1 some text goes here Some Text2 some other text goes here");
 });
```

Comment: What if the text within the links changes? Or more links are added?